# iOS : UITableView - Adding columns to your table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm looking to change the number of columns my tableview has without subclassing it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can find your happiness here: http://usxue.is-programmer.com/posts/14176.html
With that you can create a Grid and have multiples columns

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to select individual columns the you could just subclass UITableViewCell to make it LOOK like it has more than one column.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this without subclassing anything would need to be done as follows:

1) Place a UIScrollView in the view.
2) Put n amount of UITableViews embedded in the UIScrollView where n is the amount of columns desired.
3) Turn scrolling off in all of the UITableViews.
4) Make all of the UITableView frames equal to that UITableView's contentSize.
5) Set the UIScrollView's content size equal to the largest UITableView's frame.

I have not tested this because I would definitely recommend subclassing either UITableView or UITableViewCell, but this would be one way of doing it.